# Buddy or Adversary?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I’m a buddy to some, but a wary adversary to others.
>   Yet I can also be a protector to the weak.
>   You can even sometimes see me with my friend, Jack.
>   Crazy guys take my name and spout it about.
>   Some would take it as an insult but, I don’t.

What am I?

Hint 1:

> One might have to think about "Crazy guys take my name and spout it about" in a more literal sense in some parts of it.

Hint 2:

> Jack has a pet.

Hint 3:

> "Take" is similar to what happens to a female's name when married.

Hint 4:

> A word added before the answer might help solve line 2.

Hint 5:

> Try thinking of another word for crazy in line 4.

Comment: Cap'n Jack Sparrow :)

Comment: What does it mean to "spout something about"? I can't find the exact meaning on the internet.

Comment: Spouting, kind of like shout or yell.

Comment: might be time for a new hint.

Comment: @Rubio Ask and you shall receive!

Comment: Jack skellington has a pet dog called zero, but I doubt that's the one we are looking for :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> A Nut

I’m a buddy to some, but a wary adversary to others.

> Fitting a nut can be easier for a few but others take a precaution.

Yet I can also be a protector to the weak.

> It keeps the weaker and falling things intact

You can even sometimes see me with my friend, Jack.

> Jack Nut is a kind of nut.

Crazy guys take my name and spout it about.

> Nut's is a slang.

Some would take it as an insult but, I don’t.

> Saying "nuts" to someone might be an insult to a person but well, for nut its not.

**Original poster's thoughts** 
I accepted @Techidiot answer because I believe it was the closest to my original answer as possible.

Original Answer:

> a peanut. Techidiot answer was close enough.

I’m a buddy to some, but a wary adversary to others.

> Peanut butter is known as the buddy of jelly or jam. Yet some are allergic to peanuts, so they have to be wary of them.

Yet I can also be a protector to the weak.

> Packaging peanuts or just called peanuts, are used to protect fragile items when shipped.

You can even sometimes see me with my friend, Jack.

> Take me out to the ball game. Buy me some peanuts and Cracker Jacks.
> Jack of Cracker Jacks has a dog named Bingo.

Crazy guys take my name and spout it about.

> Nut guys yell "Peanuts! Get your peanuts here!" at sporting events to try to get your attention to buy some.

Some would take it as an insult but, I don’t.

> The term peanut refers to calling someone of short stature as an insult to them.

Comment: Good try but no. The answer is an object.

Comment: @Zachstein Updated another. :)

Comment: We have a winner!!!!

Comment: I'll throw up an answer explaining my actual thoughts.

Comment: Sure. Or else you can edit mine if you like. :)

Answer (score 8):

Are you a

> Union?

I'm a buddy to some, but a wary adversary to others

> Labor unions are viewed both positively and negatively, depending on who you're talking to.

Yet I can also be a protector to the weak.

> They are designed to give individual employees protection from the much more powerful corporations.

You can even sometimes see me with my friend, Jack.

> The British flag is called the Union Jack

Crazy guys take my name and spout it about.

> Many conspiracy theorists involve 'The Union' meaning the federal government of the U.S. doing things.

Some would take it as an insult but, I don’t.

> Call back to the first meaning, of Labor Union? A Union member might be looked down on by those who don't agree with Unions, thinking that they can't fight their own battles.

Comment: Nice interpretation but not the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could be

> Whiskey

I’m a buddy to some

> Some people like to drink to the extent the alcohol remains their last friend (buddy).

but a wary adversary to others.

> For others (i.e. those who cannot control themselves after they drink) it can be adversary (something dangerous or a source of humiliation).

Yet I can also be a protector to the weak.

> Some research say that whiskey is "an antidote for cancer", so the *weak* people who are afraid of cancer can be *protected* by whiskey (**according to some research**)

You can even sometimes see me with my friend, Jack.

> Jack Daniels

Crazy guys take my name and spout it about.

> Crazy guys means people that already have enough and spout the whiskey about the area as they cannot maintain their grip on the glass.

Some would take it as an insult

> People often believe that spoiling whiskey is an insult as it is a noble and expensive beverage.

but, I don’t.

> Whiskey certainly want to be used whenever possible, so even if someone spoils some it takes no offense.

Answer (score 2):

You are

> Jolly Roger

I’m a buddy to some

> Pirates

but a wary adversary to others.

> non-pirates. Also the skull and bones remind of death which is *wary adversary* to the living.

Yet I can also be a protector to the weak.

> The Blackshirts, the starting **defensive** unit players for the Nebraska Cornhuskers football team, are represented by a Jolly Roger
>  The Jolly Roger was also used on first submarines in the navy which were used for defense...

You can even sometimes see me with my friend, Jack.

> Captain Jack Sparrow :) Also one of the most popular Jolly Roger adaptations is Calico Jack's pirate flag (the one with the swords instead of bones)

Crazy guys take my name and spout it about.

> [Pirate Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirate_Party_of_Sweden) can be called "crazy guys" as their ideology is generally rather controversial. They had the Jolly Roger as their symbol few years ago. Not sure about the "take my **name**" part but still.

Some would take it as an insult but, I don’t.

> The Pirate Party wants to reform copyright and patent law which many people take as an insult for their intellectual property. But the Pirates believe it is not insulting and leads to better future (according to wikipedia linked above)

Comment: Not correct. The take my name part is key.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are:

> The joker

I’m a buddy to some, but a wary adversary to others.

> Buddy to the mobs, adversary of batman

Yet I can also be a protector to the weak.

> Not sure, probably circus jokers protect someone?

You can even sometimes see me with my friend, Jack.

> The joker playing card and the jack playing card

Crazy guys take my name and spout it about.
Some would take it as an insult but, I don’t.

> People are insulted if they are called clowns or jokers..

Comment: Sorry, nope. The funny thing is the joker was the answer to the last riddle I posted.

Answer (score 0):

you might be:

> help or support?

I’m a buddy to some, but a wary adversary to others.

> some people relay on the help of other while other's thinks it can be damaging to them.

Yet I can also be a protector to the weak.

> weak person's relay on other's help.(most of times)

You can even sometimes see me with my friend, Jack.

> jack is also a synonym of support.

Crazy guys take my name and spout it about.

> some people always try to insult those who takes help.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't fit the crazy guys taking my name.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the second hint I think you are

> a dog.

I’m a buddy to some, but a wary adversary to others.

> Dogs are human's best friends, but some people are afraid of them.

Yet I can also be a protector to the weak.

> A dog can protect its master in case of emergency.

You can even sometimes see me with my friend, Jack.

> Jack is some specific character (as OP says in comments) that has a dog.

Crazy guys take my name and spout it about.

> People tend to call other people "dogs" if they want to insult them. (OP says that another word for "crazy" helps to get this one)

Some would take it as an insult but, I don’t.

> But a dog itself would not consider it an insult.

Comment: Nope, Jack is a specific person. Maybe thinking of another word for crazy might help.

Comment: Also pet is correct.

Comment: @Zachstein Does "pet is correct" mean that Jack's pet is a dog?

Comment: @MikeQ Or that the "me" of this riddle is Jack's pet?

Comment: @MikeQ Jack's pet is a dog.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely but are you:

> Pirate **[Captain Samuel Bellamy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Bellamy)**

```
I’m a buddy to some, but a wary adversary to others.
Yet I can also be a protector to the weak.
```

> Bellamy likened himself to Robin Hood, meaning for the rich and powerful he was an enemy, but to the poor and weak a friend and protector.

```
You can even sometimes see me with my friend, Jack.
```

> Jack Sparrow is a fictional Pirate, so Bellamy and Jack would have had that in common...

```
Crazy guys take my name and spout it about.
Some would take it as an insult but, I don’t.
```

> His crew loved him and spread the word of what a great captain he was.

Comment: Alas not. Remember the hints.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot but I'm wondering if you are...

> a goose

"I’m a buddy to some, but a wary adversary to others."

> Geese can be pretty vicious when they feel threatened but are beloved pets to some

Yet I can also be a protector to the weak.

> Geese are good parents and very protective of their goslings

You can even sometimes see me with my friend, Jack.

> In Jack and the Beanstalk there is a golden goose

Crazy guys take my name and spout it about.

> I interpret this as "Mad men change my name and shout it everywhere" Not sure whether this is something "lost in translation" but my theory starts to become unstuck!

Some would take it as an insult but, I don’t.

> A goose can't be insulted by words because they don't communicate that way...

Comment: Sorry, incorrect.